# Date-timestamp clipped to show only 00:00.0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime

I recently received a .csv file where it appears that the date-timestamp was clipped. The values are in 00:00.0 format.

Doesn't seem like a pandas only issue. When I open the .csv file separately, I don't see any additional information stored. Is there a way to check if there is more information in these cells with pandas before going back to the file originator? Thanks for any tips on this!

[I attached a screenshot of what the file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XkBD.png)

Comment: First of all, welcome to SO! Then, please keep in mind that it is always best to add data/code as text instead of image/screenshot. Coming to your problem, could you add a sample of your input? The screenshot only shows the already imported state.

Comment: Likely there's no more info. CSV is just a text file. You can open it in any text editor to see the raw content of the file